# Принцип работы Comet

Tags: comet, javascript, http, веб-программирование

Доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с необходимостью внедрить технологию Comet вместо обычных AJAX запросов туда-сюда каждую секунду...

Весь день не отходил от компа, пытаясь разобраться, читая статьи и всяческие примеры. Иногда даже почти работало. Но так нормально принципа и не понял, на практике не получается(

Пожалуйста, объясните принцип работы пресловутого Comet-а, желательно с каким-нибудь простым примером, а то пытаюсь написать работающий скрипт, и по-любому что-то работает не так...

Comment: Не думаю, что пришло время commet. Не все браузеры его поддерживают! Если и получится, то только для одного-двух браузеров,  для остальных придется ajax использовать. А так можно почитать в сторону node.js

Comment: * [Может ли Сервер вызвать метод клиента?](http://hashcode.ru/questions/20014/)
* [PHP, JAVA прослушка (постоянная работа скрипта)](http://hashcode.ru/questions/25206#25343)

Answer (score 5):

> Blockquote
> Не думаю, что пришло время commet. Не все браузеры его поддерживают! Если и получится, то только для одного-двух браузеров, для остальных придется ajax использовать. А так можно почитать в сторону node.js

На счет пары браузеров готов поспорить, в каждом браузере можно реализовать подобную передачу данных, все про технологию COMET можно прочитать [тут](http://javascript.ru/ajax/comet), там же есть примеры реализации клиентских скриптов.

На сервере так же можно использовать js, хороший пример я видел на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/76144/), хорошо описано как реализуется онлайн чат.

Answer (score 1):

Хороший пример на ASP.NET MVC [Roll Your Own MVC 3 Long Polling Chat Site](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2011/04/12/roll-your-own-mvc-3-long-polling-chat-site/), [Demo](http://mvcchatsite.apphb.com/) (Откройте в 2-х бразуерах и попереписывайтесь)